# Adding/Removing duplicate divs with input fields with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input

I'd like to finish this function, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to add and remove divs called 'milestones' with various inputs inside of them with jquery. I have the 'add milestone' button working currently. Each milestone div has a 'delete milestone' button that, when clicked, should delete that div entirely. For some reason I'm not able to interact with the buttons inside those dynamically crated divs.

I'm also trying to incremement the Milestone #.

**The HTML**

```
   <!-- Milestone Title -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Milestone Title</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Milestone[0]
          [MilestoneTitle]" placeholder="Dusty Bench" required />
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>

<!-- Milestone Deadline -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Deadline</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" name="Milestone[0][MilestoneEndDate]" placeholder="Deadline" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Milestone Description -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Milestone Description</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" name="Milestone[0][Description]" rows="3" required>
      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="additional-milestones">
</div>

<!-- + Add Milestone Button -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <a class="add-milestone btn btn-primary">
       + Add Another Milestone
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Set Milestones Tab #2 -->
```

**The JQuery**

```
$().ready(function() {
  //Max amount of milestones
  var max_milestone = 5

  // Initial Milestone Count
  var x = 1;

  //function for add milestone button
  //if button.add-milestone is clicked
  $('.add-milestone').click(function(e) {
    //console.log('dope')
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_milestone) {
      x++; //increment milestones
      $('.additional-milestones').before('<h4>Milestone #1</h4><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Milestone Title</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Milestone[0][MilestoneTitle]" placeholder="Dusty Bench" required /></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Deadline</label><input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" name="Milestone[0][MilestoneEndDate]" placeholder="Deadline" required/></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Milestone Description</label><textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" name="Milestone[0][Description]" rows="3" required> </textarea></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><a class="delete-milestone btn btn-danger"> - Delete This Milestone</a></div></div><hr>');
    }
  });
  //then
  //populate with milestone form with Milestone+Next Milestone Number

  //Delete Milestone 
  $('.delete-milestone').click(function() {
    console.log('dope')
      //$(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

**The CSS**

```
.btn {
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-color: #888888;
  color: #888888;
}

.btn-primary {
  border: solid 1px #447DF7;
}

.btn-danger {
  border: #FB404B solid 1px;
}
```

My JS fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/factoryhands/okn9dbsg/1/).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is going wrong with your code is that you are attaching event handler to elements with class `.delete-milestone` initially in your code, whereas these elements are added dynamically. As a result when the code is executed, it tries to attach a event handler to the elements with class `.delete-milestone` but actually there are no elements present.

You can instead attach event handler after the element is injected into the HTML. Have a look at this modified [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VaTz88/okn9dbsg/4/) of your code.

Or you can also make use of `onclick` attribute.

And for incrementing the milestone #, you can have a separate variable to keep a count. Increment when element is added and decrement when it is deleted.

Comment: Thanks! Super fresh stack overflow user over here.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript defines the click event on .delete-milestones before it exists. You have to call .on click after it was added to the dom.

Try this:

```
$('.add-milestone').click(function() {
    $newMilestone = $('<h4>Milestone #1</h4><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Milestone Title</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Milestone[0][MilestoneTitle]" placeholder="Dusty Bench" required /></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Deadline</label><input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" name="Milestone[0][MilestoneEndDate]" placeholder="Deadline" required/></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Milestone Description</label><textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" name="Milestone[0][Description]" rows="3" required> </textarea></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><a class="delete-milestone btn btn-danger"> - Delete This Milestone</a></div></div>');
    $('.additional-milestones').before($newMilestone);
    $newMilestone.find('.delete-milestone').on('click', function() {
        console.log('dope')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the code waits for the document to become ready. It's going to run that code you posted *once*, at the beginning.

When the document is ready, `$('.delete-milestone')` will get a list of buttons that are *currently* on the page. `.click(...)` will add event listeners to them.

Later, if you add more buttons, no code adds event listeners to them.

Here are two ideas on how to make it work:

1. When you create a button, add an event listener.
2. Use [delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to handle events on anything that matches a selector that bubbles up to a common ancestor.